# Преобразование списка строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна функция `fix_duplicates`, которая будет принимать на вход список строк-идентификаторов и исправлять их так, чтобы в результирующем списке не было дубликатов. Для этого она будет прибавлять к повторяющимся идентификаторам постфикс "_n", где n - количество раз, сколько такой идентификатор уже встречался.

Примеры:

```
ids = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "c"]

fix_duplicates(ids) == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'd', 'c_1']
```

Я начала решать через `for` :

```
 def fix_duplicates(ids):
    for i in range(len(ids)):
        if ids[i] == ids[i]:
            s = ids[i] + '_' + '1' 
    return s 
    
 fix_duplicates(ids)
```

Но есть следующие проблемы:

- я не знаю как работать со списками так, чтобы вычислить сколько раз встречается тот или иной символ и как понять, что символы повторяются (то есть как это обозначить)
- и вообще как так можно сделать?

Comment: вычислить сколько раз встречается тот или иной символ - `лист.count(символ)`

Comment: я вообще на верном пути, решая через фор?

Comment: да, на правильном

Comment: А какой должен быть результат для списка `["a_1_1", "a_1", "a", "a"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

смотрим, сколько раз до текущего встречался такой же, и добавляем суффикс, если был хотя бы раз

```
def fix_duplicates(ids):
    res = []
    for i,v in enumerate(ids) :
        c = ids[:i].count(v)
        if  c:
            res.append(v+'_'+str(c))
        else:
            res.append(v)
    return res
```

Comment: А интересно, если использовать set и try, except - быстрее или медленнее будет

Comment: Кст, как насчет того, чтобы не делать срез от строки, а помещать индекс в `count`? Параметры для этого есть: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Comment: @gil9red и что, это теперь повод для даунвойта?

Comment: @splash58, 1) это не я 2) в последний раз я минус ставил в 2018 году 3) это я вам плюс поставил

Comment: Понятно, по времени просто совпало с комментом, извините. Но было бы здорово понять, что кому-то не понравилось

Answer (score 3):

вот еще идея, так, для разнообразия:

```
ids = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "c"]

def myfunc(a: list) -> list:
    d={}
    res=[]
    for x in a:
        d.setdefault(x,0)
        res.append(x+'_'*bool(d[x])+str(d[x])*bool(d[x]))
        d[x]+=1
    return res

print(myfunc(ids))
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'd', 'c_1']

Comment: может лучше воспользоваться `d = collections.defaultdict(int)` или `d.get(x, 0)` вместо `d[x]`?

Comment: с collections у меня тоже был вариант, но не захотел еще один модуль загружать. с d.get() вообще был вариант изначально, но я посчитал сочетание setdefault и get не очень красивым.

Comment: как на счет: `res.append(f"{x}_{d[x]}" if x in d else x); d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1` и тогда нам становится не нужен `d.setdefault(x,0)`?

Comment: @MaxU здорово, но это будет уже не мой ответ ;)